# Permissions in postman

Tags: postman, aspnetboilerplate, abp

Through swagger I access api endpoint without permissions, but when I try the same api endpoint with postman I end up having permission error returned to me: *Required permissions are not granted.*

Edit:
Here are some pictures:
[image: This is how I get token]

[image: This is from documentation, it shows permissions, but not in my case]

[image]

Token in inherited from parent auth, which just contains bearer token.

The same api called from swagger:
[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: Need more detail, like what are the params is passed in header while you call from swagger? and it'd be more helpful if you can show us the both the requests

Comment: I updated my question.